# Cannot open a separate window as an underlying tab in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to open a separate window (as an underlying window) of the current window. I have attached a simple code segment which I used. But in Chrome there is a popup blocked message appeared when I do this. It means that The separate window is not recognized as a window, it still considered as a popup. How can I do this ? Any suggestions would be really appreciated

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>JS Window example</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function windowonload()
{
    window.open("http://yahoo.com", "sameera", "height=200,width=200");
}
</script>
<body onload="javascript: windowonload()">
<h1>JS Window example</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean? If you add a third parameter to window open it is a separate window and will be blocked by a pop up blocker. What is confusing about that? Also you can drop the javascript: label in the onload

Answer (score 0):

you can use iframe tag like this wherever you want to show the window

```
<iframe src="http://yahoo.com"></iframe>
```